# Re-attatching an X server view of a lost process

Tags: linux, qt, session, daemon

I'm running Xorg and my (Qt) program daemonises itself. Now I log out and restart the X server. When I log in again my process is still running fine, but I can't see it.

Is there a way of attatching the new incarnation of the X server to the old process?
If I don't restart the whole server, but log out and in again, is there a way to look at the old process?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

xpra should achieve your requirement. And it can also start tcp connection (without need of ssh). Start it on the you server:

```
xpra start :100 --start-child=xterm --bind-tcp=0.0.0.0:10000
```

Connect it on your client:

```
xpra attach tcp:SERVERHOST:10000
```

You can also use mac or windows xpra app to connect it. I tried in on win7 and osx10.10.2. The download link:

windows: https://www.xpra.org/dists/windows/Xpra_Setup.exe
mac: https://www.xpra.org/dists/osx/x86/Xpra.dmg

Answer (score 1):

After the connection to the X server is lost, it is not possible to regain it.

There was an xserver proxy called xmove, but it is quite deprecated and doesn't work with several newer X extension, which are likely used by modern toolkits.

You could try to run your process in another virtual X server like xvnc or (better) NX. NX is a X proxy technology developed by NoMachine. There exist free implementations of NX servers as well.
If you run your program inside such a server, it is possible to attach and detach from it from arbitrary graphical environments.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [Xpra](http://xpra.org/): it allows you to run applications on an off-screen X11 server to which you can re-attach whenever needed, and from remote machines too. It supports "seamless" sessions too so the windows will appear just like local windows.

Practical example:

`xpra start :10 --start-child=/bin/YOURAPP`

Then whenever you want to re-attach (say after an X11 server restart):

`xpra attach :10`

Or from a remote machine:

`xpra attach ssh://THESERVERHOSTNAMEORIP/10`